# how to passing data from method C# to page.aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays

Actually, I have data from the database, and I brought it to the behind code C# in list `List<int> Data = new List<int>()` successfully

**codebehind**

```
Controllers.clsConnexion c = new Controllers.clsConnexion();//class connexion 

c.Seconnecter();
c.mthDataset("select cases from charts", null);//Method Dataset

int i=0;
public List<int> Data = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow row in c.dt.Rows)
{
   Data.Add(int.Parse(row[0].ToString()));
}
//DONE !
```

but I tried again and again using tage like this `<%= %>` to pass  data from my List to JS script in `page.aspx` without any result

```
<script>
    var NewItem;
    var NewList=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < <%=Data%>.length; i++) {
        NewItem= <%=Data[i]%>;
        NewList.push(NewItem);
    }
</script>
```

Note: I'm just a beginner in learning ASP.NET and JS

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the list between script tags?

Comment: you're trying to pass data to JS. But this is not going to happen. If you want to pass data to JS, build JSON array .

Comment: in fact I am working on a chart... and that list that i created  is a data from database  that I want to display on the chart using javascript